# sql skipping reader

Tags: c#, sql

Hello I am trying to run a method that returns me a list of bills. However the method is failing and the application goes into break mode.

After debugging the problem occurs after this line `billDetail.InvoiceTotal = reader.GetInt64(0);` is read. I don't get any exceptions and the next step takes me to the finally block without returning anything. I am a little confused as to why this is happening.

I have tested the query and that works fine and returns what it should do.

my code:

```
 public List<BillDetails> getBillDetails(long id, long clientid)
    {
        string SQLServerToUse = "blah blah";
        string SQLServerDB = "amaya";
        string SQLServerPWD = "pass";
        string SQLServerUser = "sa";

        //set the connection string
        string connString = "Data Source=" + SQLServerToUse + ";Initial Catalog=" + SQLServerDB + ";User ID=" + SQLServerUser + ";Password=" + SQLServerPWD + ";";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);

        connection.Open();

        List<BillDetails> bills = new List<BillDetails>();

        try
        {
            string query = @"SELECT InvoiceTotal, Tax, Transcount, Services, ORC
                            FROM history 
                            WHERE id = @id";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var billDetail = new BillDetails();
                        billDetail.InvoiceTotal = reader.GetInt64(0);
                        billDetail.Tax = reader.GetDouble(1);
                        billDetail.Transcount = reader.GetInt32(2);
                        billDetail.Services = reader.GetDouble(3);
                        billDetail.ORC = reader.GetDouble(4);
                        bills.Add(billDetail);
                    }

                    reader.Close();
                }
            }

            return bills;
        }

        catch (SqlException ex) // This will catch all SQL exceptions
        {
            string query = @"INSERT INTO Amaya_Errors(CustID, TimeStamp, ErrorMessage) 
                             VALUES(@CustID, @TimeStamp, @ErrorMessage)";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", clientid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeStamp", DateTime.Now);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ErrorMessage", ex.Message);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex) // This will catch SqlConnection Exception
        {
            string query = @"INSERT INTO Amaya_Errors(CustID, TimeStamp, ErrorMessage) 
                             VALUES(@CustID, @TimeStamp, @ErrorMessage)";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", clientid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeStamp", DateTime.Now);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ErrorMessage", ex.Message);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking on those lines and using "Quick Watch" to see the evaluation of the statements? That would show you any errors. Also on a separate note I don't think writing to the database in the catch blocks is a good idea. You're already duplicating the code each time. Your method should return a value that determines whether it was successful or not, and then call your logging method after reading that value.

Comment: check data type of InvoiceTotal in billDetail class .ithink it did not match it should be the type long

Comment: @LeeWillis very good point. i Will implement the change.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your thrown exception is not type of `SqlException`, `InvalidOperationException`.

So your program flow looks like this:

1. `catch` blocks are not executed because thrown exception is not type of `SqlException`, `InvalidOperationException`
2. `finally` is executed. As `finally` is always executed.

So you need to catch `Exception`:

```
try
{    
    // the other code is omitted for the brevity
}
catch (SqlException ex) // This will catch only SqlException
{   
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex) // This will catch only InvalidOperationException 
{         
}
catch (Exception ex) // This will catch all exceptions
{            
}
finally
{
     connection.Close();
}
```